# insert into в php

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как могу сделать запрос insert into в обычном стиле а не ооп

Comment: Очевидно используя процедурный стиль.

Comment: А чем вас ООП не устраивает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$conn = new mysqli('host','user','password','db');

if(!$conn){
   die(":(");
}

$add = $conn->query("INSERT INTO myTable (field1,field2,field3) VALUES ('val1','val2','val3');");

if($add){
  echo "SUCCESS";
}else{
  echo "ERROR";
}
```

Comment: Вопрошающий не хотел ООП

Answer (score 1):

посмотрите тут: http://php.net/mysqli_query

```
mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO table VALUES (...)");
```